# Updating a section of RichTextBox C#

Tags: c#, text, richtextbox

I'm working on a very simple order form that will be printed via a label printer.
I have a `richTextBox` to display which items have been added and how many but what I can't figure out is how to edit a "section" of the text box is multiple items of the same item is added.

I currently have 2 buttons, 1 for Chicken and one for Salmon.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chickenCount++;
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\nChicken " + chickenCount + "x";
    }
```

and

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        salmonCount++;
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\nSalmon " + salmonCount + "x";
    }
```

So let's say you add 1 chicken then 1 salmon and after that, you add another chicken.

With this code the output would be:

```
Chicken 1x
Salmon 1x
Chicken 2x
```

Now I know that this code just keeps adding text on the next row of the `richTextBox`

But what I want the output to be is:

```
Chicken 2x
Salmon 1x
```

But I'm not really sure how to edit something inline of the `richTextBox`

Comment: Can't you rewrite the whole content of the richtextbox?

Comment: ??? a) wouldn't you want Chicken 3x ??? b) why use a RichtTextBox?? c) if you want formatting you never must change the Text directly!! d) you need to keep a list or dictionary  with your data to do the math __before__ creating text e) how do you plan to prnt? The RTB will not help you there!

Comment: You could use an [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) and update the `RichTextBox` whenever it changes (entirely rewrite it)

Comment: a) No, per my example the button has only been pressed twice. But since the button just adds text on the next row the last Chicken is the correct one so I wanted to be able to overwrite the first one. So Chicken 2x is correct. b) I'm a novice programmer, this was the way I thought of doing it. e) It's printing to a Dymo Label writer via the dymo SDK. I already got that working.

Comment: Thank you Emanuel and Rene, I'll take a look at that approach! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SelectedText` property and the `Select` method to replace a line on the text box. For example:

```
int line = 0; //The line that we want to replace is the first one
string newstr = "Chicken x2"; //We want to replace the line with this string
int charindex = this.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line); //Get the index of the first character of the line
richTextBox1.Select(charindex, richTextBox1.Lines[line].Length); //Select the line
richTextBox1.SelectedText = newstr; //Replace its text with the string
```

If you don't know which line you want to replace, loop through the `Lines` array searching for the text.